# Why does UI-Grid Selection throws JS error

Tags: angular-ui-grid

The ui-grid in the code was working perfectly and suddenly started throwing

> Uncaught TypeError: row.setSelected is not a function
>       at Object.toggleRowSelection (ui-grid.js:247923)
>       at HTMLDivElement.selectCells (ui-grid.js:248324)
>       at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery:1)
>       at HTMLDivElement.y.handle (jquery:1)

I am registering the gridApi as below

The Grid renders fine, but on selecting any row, the above error is thrown.

```
    $scope.uigParticipant = {
        enableRowSelection: false,
        multiSelect: true, 
        enableRowHeaderSelection: true,
        enableColumnMenus: false,
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableSorting : true,
        treeRowHeaderAlwaysVisible: false,
        enablePaginationControls: true,
        paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 75, 100],
        paginationPageSize: 25,
        exporterMenuCsv: true,
        exporterMenuPdf: false,
        enableGridMenu: true,
        enableAutoFitColumns: true,
        showTreeExpandNoChildren: true,
        CanUserFreezeColumns: false,
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
            gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (rows) {
                $scope.mySelections = gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
            });
        },
        columnDefs: [


        { name: 'Id', displayName: 'ID', width: '25%', headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader, headerCellClass: 'grid-align-center', cellClass: 'grid-align-center' },
        { name: 'Name', displayName: 'Name', width: '25%', headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader },

        { name: 'DOB', displayName: 'Date of Birth', type: 'date', cellFilter: 'date:"dd/MM/yyyy"', width: '25%', headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader, headerCellClass: 'grid-align-center', cellClass: 'grid-align-center' },
            { name: 'PhoneNo', displayName: 'Phone', width: '25%', headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader, headerCellClass: 'grid-align-center', cellClass: 'grid-align-center' }
            //{ name: 'Program', displayName: 'Program', width: '20%', headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader, headerCellClass: 'grid-align-center', cellClass: 'grid-align-center' }
        //{ name: 'RegisteredDate', displayName: 'Registered Date', width: '20%', headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader },
        ]
    };
```

Please provide some thoughts. Has there been any changes to the ui-grid-selection recently.
This started happening in all the applications involving ui-grid.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known bug in 4.7.x.  See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/6928